# HTML5 code semantic for a footer

Tags: html

what is the best option for the HTML code of my website's footer?

This:

```
  <footer class="clearfix">
    <footer class="footer-top-bar">footer top bar</footer>
    <footer class="footer-left">footer left</footer>
    <footer class="footer-middle">footer middle</footer>
    <footer class="footer-right">footer right</footer>
  </footer>
```

or this:

```
  <footer class="clearfix">
    <div class="footer-top-bar"></div>
    <div class="footer-left"></div>
    <div class="footer-middle"></div>
    <div class="footer-right"></div>
  </footer>
```

Thanks,

Comment: 2nd option. What's the reasoning of having `<footer>` sub elements inside a `<footer>`?

Comment: the second one.  you only need one `<footer>` element.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to W3, the following rules are applied for the `footer` tag:

> - The element footer must not appear as a descendant of the header element.
> - The element footer must not appear as a descendant of the footer element.
> - The element footer must not appear as a descendant of the address element.

So, to answer your question, option one is not valid HTML markup.  Use Option 2 over Option 1.

*Source:* http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/footer.html

Comment: Why use option 1? It violates the W3 specification (based on the section you've posted).

Comment: Had a minor brain fart and flipped the two in my head when writing the answer. I fixed it haha